# CardView Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to make CardView

I have this code for Adapter:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;

namespace NavDrawer.Adapters
{

    public class RecyclerAdapter<T, V> : RecyclerView.Adapter where V : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> _Collection;
        int _ResourceId;
        Action<T, V> _UpdateViewHolder;
        public RecyclerAdapter(ObservableCollection<T> collection, int resourceId, Action<T, V> viewHolderUpdateAction)
        {
            _ResourceId = resourceId;
            _Collection = collection;
            _Collection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
            _UpdateViewHolder = viewHolderUpdateAction;
        }
        ~RecyclerAdapter()
        {
            _Collection.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
        }
        public override int ItemCount { get { return _Collection.Count; } }
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            var viewHolder = holder as V;
            var item = _Collection[position];
            _UpdateViewHolder(item, viewHolder);
        }
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(_ResourceId, parent, false);
            return (V)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(V), new object[] { itemView });
        }
        public T GetItem(int index)
        {
            return ((_Collection != null && index < _Collection.Count) ? _Collection[index] : default(T));
        }
        public void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            if (_Collection != null && index < _Collection.Count) { _Collection.RemoveAt(index); }
        }
        public void InsertItemAt(int index, T item)
        {
            if (_Collection != null && index < _Collection.Count) { _Collection.Insert(index, item); }
        }
        public new Type GetType()
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
        void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    NotifyItemInserted(e.NewStartingIndex);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    NotifyItemRemoved(e.OldStartingIndex);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    NotifyItemChanged(e.OldStartingIndex);
                    NotifyItemChanged(e.NewStartingIndex);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    NotifyItemRemoved(e.OldStartingIndex);
                    NotifyItemRemoved(e.NewStartingIndex);
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This to ViewHolder:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;

namespace NavDrawer.Adapters
{
    public class SponsorsViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView Sponsor { get; private set; }
        public TextView Sponsordescription { get; private set; }

        public SponsorsViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
            : base(itemView)
        {
            Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.sponsorimage);
            Sponsor = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sponsorstitle);
            Sponsordescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sponsorsdescription);
        }

        /*void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SomeAction != null)
            {
                SomeAction();
            }*/
        }
    }
```

And here is my Fragment where I need to show CardView:

```
  using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using NavDrawer.Activities;
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using TaskStackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder;
using Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging.Fragments;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging.Attributes;
using NavDrawer.Core.ViewModels;
using Android.Runtime;
using NavDrawer.DownloadClasses;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static NavDrawer.Activities.FirstView;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using NavDrawer.Adapters;

namespace NavDrawer.Fragments
{
    [MvxFragment(typeof(HomeViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
    [Register("navdrawer.fragments.SponsorsFragment")]
    public class SponsorsFragment : MvxFragment<SponsorsViewModel>
    {




        public class Sponsors
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string company_name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string sponsor_level { get; set; }
            public string picture { get; set; }
            public string location { get; set; }
            public string website_url { get; set; }
            public string sm_twitter { get; set; }
            public string sm_facebook { get; set; }
            public string sm_linkedin { get; set; }
            public string sm_pinterest { get; set; }
            public string contact_number { get; set; }
            public string attachments { get; set; }
            public string date_time { get; set; }


        }



        public SponsorsFragment()
        {
            this.RetainInstance = true;


        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SponsorsList, null);
            GetAllSponsor sponsorlist = new GetAllSponsor();
            sponsorlist.getallsponsor();
            string spnsrlst = sponsorlist.ToFormattedJsonString();

            List<Sponsors> sponsorObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sponsors>>(spnsrlst);

            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity));
            recyclerView.SetAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter<Sponsors, SponsorsViewHolder>(Spnsr, Resource.Layout.SponsorsCard));





        return view;
    }



}
```

}

I have some questions:

1. I cant find recyclerview via this code `var recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);`
2. How I need to write code to pass json data to ObservableCollection?

Anybody can help me?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

mate.

In your SponsorsList layout, do you have the RecyclerView view?

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

I didn't quite catch what you mean by your second question but isn't it what you were willing?

```
recyclerView.SetAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter<Sponsors, SponsorsViewHolder>(sponsorObjectData, Resource.Layout.SponsorsCard));
```

I replaced Spnsr with sponsorObjectData.

I would recommend you reading the following: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/ and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-music-app-using-xamarin-sitecore-part-3-jo%C3%A3o-amancio-neto?trk=mp-author-card.